# Api_channel_fields - cannot add group id

Tags: custom-fields, api

I'm trying to add a new field to a group using the API but it doesn't work (according to the docs it is supposed to be a key).

I have tried running the example code but the 'group_id' field is ignored when I add it to the field object sent to the update_field method:

```
        ee()->load->library('api');
        ee()->legacy_api->instantiate('channel_fields');
        $field_data = array(
            'site_id' => 1,
            'group_id' => 1,
            'field_name' => 'aaaa',
            'field_label' => 'AAAA',
            'field_type' => 'text',
            'field_order' => 10,
            'field_required' => 'y',
            'field_search' => 'y',
            'field_is_hidden' => 'n',
            'field_instructions' => '',
            'field_maxl' => 128,
            'text_field_fmt' => 'none',
            'text_field_show_fmt' => 'n',
            'text_field_text_direction' => 'ltr',
            'text_field_content_type' => 'all',
            'text_field_show_smileys' => 'n',
            'text_field_show_glossary' => 'n',
            'text_field_show_spellcheck' => 'n',
            'text_field_show_file_selector' => 'n',
        );

        ee()->api_channel_fields->update_field($field_data);
```

So I added a call to field_edit_vars prior to the update_field call as stated in the docs:

```
    $vars = ee()->api_channel_fields->field_edit_vars(1, FALSE);
    ee()->load->view('admin/field_edit', $vars, TRUE);
```

But I get 'Call to undefined method Api_channel_fields::field_edit_vars()'

I've also tried using the return value from the 'update_field' method, which according to the docs should be the new field id but it returns nothing.

How do I add the new field to a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this using API. I think you should try with **EE Model**. You can easily create new `field` using the Model. And Model is most effective way to handle all these core things.

You can create new field using below **Model** code.

```
$field = ee('Model')->make('ChannelField');        
$field->site_id = 0;
$field->field_name = 'your_field_name';
$field->field_label = 'Your Field Label';
$field->field_type = 'text';
$field->field_pre_populate = 'n';                
$field->field_ta_rows = '6';
$field->field_maxl = '256';
$field->field_required = 'n';
$field->field_text_direction = 'ltr';
$field->field_search = 'n';
$field->field_is_hidden = 'n';
$field->field_fmt = 'xhtml';
$field->field_show_fmt = 'n';
$field->field_order = '10';
$field->field_content_type = 'any';
$field->field_settings = '';
$field->legacy_field_data = 'n';                
$field->save();
```

**To create Select field :-**

```
$field = ee('Model')->make('ChannelField');        
$field->site_id = 0;
$field->field_name = 'my_dropdown';
$field->field_label = 'My Dropdown';
$field->field_type = 'select';
$field->field_pre_populate = 'n';                
$field->field_ta_rows = '6';
$field->field_maxl = '';
$field->field_required = 'n';
$field->field_text_direction = 'ltr';
$field->field_search = 'n';
$field->field_is_hidden = 'n';
$field->field_fmt = 'xhtml';
$field->field_show_fmt = 'y';
$field->field_order = '10';
$field->field_content_type = 'any';
$field->field_settings = '';
$field->legacy_field_data = 'n';                
$field->save();
```

I hope this code will work for you. I have added code to create select field.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but when I tried adding '$field->group_id = 1;' it fails 'No such property:'

Comment: @wot This is most likely because that isn't part of the a channel field model; you need modify a `ChannelFieldGroup` model to add fields to it to a group. In EE4+, channel fields are independent of field groups.

Comment: @wot In this Model query `group_id` will not pass because as jrothafer said, EE has defined separate model for `group_id`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to populate a select field?

Comment: @wot I have added code to populate `select` field. Please see my modified answer.